# Changing Meteor Servers

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, meteor, galaxy

I'm working on switching my Meteor app from Galaxy to AWS, and it's currently running on both, linking to the same MongoDB, with the same user, but users created on the Galaxy server, can't login on the AWS server.  Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Comment: What users are you talking about?

Comment: @error2007s Sorry, I mean I'm using exactly the same details to connect to the MongoDB, but I don't seem to be getting any data from it, it just seems to be using a local database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, just had to change "setupMongo" to false.

Comment: This has changed in the latest version of Meteor Up, you now need to change severOnly to false.